In Javascript / Node.JS parse XML and extract attributes of the parent node
I'm using @xmldom/xmldom's DOMParser and xpath to process an XML document.
I locate a set of nodes that match an XPath expression e.g. //MyElement. I'm getting the expected elements back. I can print the values for attributes for those elements by calling node.getAttribute(attrName). So far so good... Now, I want to read attributes of the parent.
I call node.parentNode and I can print its contents using console.log. It contains (for instance):
    {
  _nsMap: {},
  attributes: {
    '0': Attr {
      ownerDocument: [Document],
      nodeName: 'myLocalName',
      name: 'myLocalName',
      namespaceURI: undefined,
      specified: true,
      localName: 'myLocalName',
      lineNumber: 1,
      columnNumber: 12828,
      nodeValue: 'someValue',     
      value: 'someValue',
      ownerElement: [Circular *1]
    },
    '1': Attr {
      ownerDocument: [Document],
      nodeName: 'someName',
      name: 'someName',
      namespaceURI: undefined,
      specified: true,
      localName: 'someName',
      lineNumber: 1,
      columnNumber: 12960,
      nodeValue: 'some value',
      value: 'some value',
      ownerElement: [Circular *1]
    },

But, for some reason I cannot call node.parentNode.attributes nor can I get access to any of the members of the attributes object unless I iterate over the keys of the parent node. What am I missing?
Code that works
    console.log("\nNODE\n");
    let ks = Object.keys(node.parentNode);
    ks.forEach((k)=>{
        if (k==='attributes'){
            let aks = Object.keys(node.parentNode['attributes']);
            console.log('Dealing with attributes');
            console.log(aks);
        }
    });

Output
NODE

Dealing with attributes
[ '0', '1', '2', '_ownerElement', 'length' ]

Code that fails
    console.log("\nNODE\n");
    let ks = Object.keys(node.parentNode);
    let aks = Object.keys(node.parentNode['attributes']);
    ks.forEach((k)=>{
        if (k==='attributes'){
            console.log('Dealing with attributes');
            console.log(aks);
        }
    });

Output
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at parseBlocks (C:\Users\david\workspace\domain-analyzer\index.js:30:26)

What am I missing?
Thanks

May be //someParent[MyElement] to get the whole parent and then use //MyElement at that node.
